# Bluemix Maven SpringBoot Build and Deploy Invalid Target Release

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, ibm-cloud

I have created a maven project and attached it to the Bluemix integrated git repository.

I can build and run this locally (either through cmd or Spring Tool Suite) using the **spring-boot:run** goal.

Others can also pull the code down from Origin and run it fine on their local machines.

The issue I am having is building and deploying this through Bluemix' build & deploy functionality. All seems fine until the following errors are presented: (Invalid target release: 1.8)

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project StudyPlaner: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I understand that this error is around the java install, and the solution is generally to ensure the java install and environment variables are set correctly on the machine running the program. However, I am unsure how to edit these values within the Bluemix Cloud. Do I need to attach Java runtime microservice for example, or is there a default java version avaliable?

[image]

The Java version is set as 1.8 in the project's POM.xml.

Any ideas on how I can progress this?

Also, we are planning on using containers going forward, but thought that deploying without containers is a logical first step.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default version that is set Java 7.  Java 8 is available.  You can take a look at the various versions that are installed in the build environment [here](https://hub.jazz.net/docs/deploy_var/#resources).  In order to use Java 8, you can add the following to the start of the build script.

`export JAVA_HOME=~/java8
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Works a treat. I've saved that link also has some very useful stuff on there. Thank you @crjenkins89

Comment: I tried the official guide https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/05/05/liberty-buildpack-updates-java-8-java-ee-7-updates/ but it didn't work. This answer worked! Thanks!

Comment: @crjenkins89 - I solved the problem with this, thanks. In my case I added this to my build configuration just before the mvn install. Also you don't need to add a maven plugin to pom.

Comment: @crjenkins89 thanks i was getting no maven compiler plugin error, i tried updating the JDK 8 version using runtime available from dashboard with the values JBP_CONFIG_IBMJDK : version: 1.8.+ but was getting the same error, you saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

Update for IBM Cloud Delivery Pipeline.

You just have to add this simple line before "mvn -B package" in order to use Java 8 for your build:

```
export JAVA_HOME="$JAVA8_HOME"
```

See the official IBM Cloud documentation page for environment variables: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ContinuousDelivery/pipeline_deploy_var.html#deliverypipeline_environment